# Intermittent keyboard key mafunction with specific keys

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

I am using an Alienware 17 with Windows 7. Intermittently, the *9, i, o, l, >, and number pad 5* keys stop working. If I long-press one of those keys for several seconds, they start working again... until the next time they become unresponsive once again (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours, days, or longer).

This issue has been occurring off and on for a few months. I just went through a month-plus period without any malfunctions of this sort, when suddenly they started up again yesterday.

I have removed and reattached those specific keys, but cannot find any crud or other physically-limiting element beneath the keys. The laptop has never been dropped and has never been spilled-on.

Any ideas on troubleshooting/fixes?

Thanks!

Comment: Verify if the problem also happens with an external keyboard.  Sounds like an issue with the physical laptop keyboard to me.

Comment: The problem is not occurring with the external keyboard, so i guess I am off to find a replacement for the laptop keyboard. Thanks!

Comment: I did this about 8-10 years ago with the wife's laptop that one of our kids spilled water on.  Disassemble, get the part number, check online sales and auction sites.  Be prepared to get a non-functional part, so make sure you check user reviews for the seller to make sure they're good about supporting their stuff.  Also, if that Alienware is from after Dell bought them, you may be able to use the part from a similar Dell model.